# RichFaces InputNumberSlider add element to div

Tags: jsf, slider, richfaces

I want to create an integer-slider and want to add it to a div. Unfortunately it seems that 
InputNumberSliderTag doesn't extend or implement UIComponent, so I am not able to add it to a div. Eclipse tells me, that there is a problem on the add()-line.

```
Div inputContainer = new Div();
InputNumberSliderTag slider = new InputNumberSliderTag();
inputContainer.getChildren().add(slider);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InputNumberSliderTag` is the tag class, meaning the implementation of the functionality for the `<rich:inputslider/>` tag. The class you want is `HtmlInputNumberSlider` inside the `org.richfaces.component.html` package which is the implementation of `UIComponent`